# Como apagar Placeholder de Input ao Clicar dentro do Campo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de saber como apagar o `placeholder` de um `input` ao clicar dentro dele. Ao pesquisar aqui vi respostas de como apagar o `value` mas não encontrei nada a respeito do `placeholder`.

Eu gostaria de uma ajuda que não seja necessário chamar a função dentro do `input`, ex:

```
<input type="text" id="input" value="Value" onClick="func()"/>
```

### Meu Código:

```
<form action="enviar.php" method="post" class="wpcf7-form">

    <input type="text" name="nome" value="" size="40" class="classe_form_1" placeholder="Seu nome (obrigatório)"><br>

    <input type="email" name="email" value="" size="40" class="classe_form_1" placeholder="Seu e-mail (obrigatório)"><br>

    <input type="text" name="assunto" value="" size="40" class="classe_form_1" placeholder="Assunto (obrigatório)"><br>

    <textarea name="mensagem" cols="40" rows="10" class="classe_form_2" placeholder="Mensagem (obrigatório)"></textarea><br>
    <button type="submit" class="botao_contato" id="botao-contato">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Você diz apagar assim que clicar, mesmo sem a pessoa começar a digitar?

Comment: Isso mesmo @GuilhermeLautert

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A função do placeholder é ajudar a explicar a funcionalidade ou conteúdo que o input deve ter. Esse placeholder desaparece quando se começa a escrever no input. Para fazer com que apague quando o input tiver em foco podes fazer assim:

```
$(':input').on('focus', function() {
    this.dataset.placeholder = this.placeholder;
    this.placeholder = '';
}).on('blur', function(){
    this.placeholder = this.dataset.placeholder;
});
```

A ideia é transferir essa informação para um campo `data-` no momento do foco, e restaurar quando deixar de estar em foco.

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jw3uyn36/

O seletor [`:input`](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) funciona para `input`, `textarea`e `select`.

Comment: e como coloco para que o código só seja usado especificamente nas classes deste formulário, no caso `classe_form_1` e `classe_form_2` ?

Comment: @Wendell nesse caso podes apontar o seletor diretamente assim: `$('.classe_form_1, .classe_form_2').on('focus', ...etc`.

Comment: Bem mais simples que em JS puro, eu demorei para postar.

Answer (score 1):

Também da pra fazer com CSS:

```css
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: transparent;
}
input:focus:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: transparent;  
}
input:focus::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: transparent;  
}
input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: transparent;  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Seu nome (obrigatório)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Monteu com JS puro.

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
  var input = inputs[i];
  input.addEventListener('focus', function(){
    var place = this.getAttribute('placeholder');
    this.setAttribute('placeholder', '');
    var blur = function(){
      this.setAttribute('placeholder', place);
    }
    this.addEventListener('blur', blur);
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="nome" value="" size="40" class="classe_form_1" placeholder="Seu nome (obrigatório)"><br>
```

Comment: Dessa maneira cada vez que houver um `focus` num elemento ele vai adicionar um novo `.addEventListener` ao elemento que nunca é removido.

Comment: Verdade @Sergio esqueci-me desta questão, mas seria um `blur` correto? pois `focus` ele só faz a primeira vez.

Comment: @Sergio me corrija se eu estiver errado, mas apenas nominando a função, não tonado mais ela anonima, ja impedi o criação de multiplos eventos com mesmo efeito, correto? não ha necessidade de usar o `removeEventListener`

Comment: O problema mantem-se mesmo assim. Dá uma olhada aqui na consola: https://jsfiddle.net/jw3uyn36/1/

Comment: @Sergio Mas isso so mostra que a função esta sendo disparada, não que estou sobrecarregando a memoria com multiplas referencias.

Comment: @Sergio [Multiple identical event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Multiple_identical_event_listeners)

Comment: olha a contagem, vai crescendo exponencialmente.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46801/discussion-between-guilherme-lautert-and-sergio).